# Complexity class definition issue

Tags: time-complexity

What is the exact definition (formal and informal) of co-P?

Like P  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_(complexity))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you have a complexity class **X**, then class co-**X** consists of all problems that are the complements of problems in **X**. For example, the class **NP** (intuitively) corresponds to problems where if the answer to the question is "yes," then there is some quick way of checking that answer. The class co-**NP** therefore consists of problems where if the answer is "no," then there is some quick way of checking that answer. The problem of "here's a Boolean formula; is there some way to assign the variables values to make it true?" is a canonical example of a problem in **NP** because if the answer is "yes," you can easily convince someone - just show them how to set each variable to make the whole thing evaluate to true. The problem of "here's a Boolean formula; is it always true?" is a canonical example of a problem in co-**NP** because if the answer is "no," you can quickly convince someone of this by just showing them a variable assignment that makes the formula evaluate to false.

The class co-**P** is well-defined, but basically no one refers to it because **P** = co-**P**. Intuitively, this is because the class **P** consists of all problems that can be solved efficiently. In that sense, if you have a problem R whose *complement* can be solved efficiently, then you can solve R easily - solve R's complement, then flip the result. Formally speaking, you can prove this by showing that any polynomial-time decider for a language in co-**P** can be converted in to a polynomial-time decider for a language in **P** (and vice-versa) by just negating the output of that decider.